# Calling a method from a JUint test which creates a failure

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automation

From my JUnit test I want to call this method, it lets me call it however even though it is supposed to cause an error it passes the test instead of failing.

```
public void handleErrors(String string, boolean b) {
    System.out.println(string + ", " + b);
    if(b == false){
        collector.addError(new Throwable(string + ", " + b));
    }   
}
```

If I pass this in which should cause a failure in the test it should fail but it does not.

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    handleErrors("Button was found", false);
}
```

Why isn't JUint reporting a failure?

EDIT:

```
package com.selenium.tests;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector;
import com.selenium.AbstractScreenTest;
public class test1 extends AbstractScreenTest{

@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector= new ErrorCollector();

@Before
public void initialize() {
createTest();
}

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
handleErrors("Button was found", false);
}

public void handleErrors(String string, boolean b) {
System.out.println(string + ", " + b);
if(b == false){
collector.addError(new Throwable(string + ", " + b));
}   
}

@After
public void tearDown(){
closeTest();
}

}
```

Comment: Why should this fail?  It doesn't throw an exception and the test doesn't assert anything.

Comment: As I'm passing in false and if it is false it adds a new throw-able error and it works when I have it in the JUint test file but not in this separate class.

Comment: Please show us the code that works.  But as that test is written, nothing would cause it to fail.  A test will fail if an exception is thrown (technically a throwable) or an assertion fails and neither is occurring in your example.

Comment: See edit. This works and produces the error, the only difference between the two code is that the method is in the JUnit test class rather than being called for a different class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this. I did not move the

```
@Rule public ErrorCollector collector= new ErrorCollector();
```

line.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you didn't annotate collector with @Rule. And it should be ErrorCollector. There is an example from API doc:

```
public static class UsesErrorCollectorTwice {
    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector= new ErrorCollector();

    @Test
    public void example() {
            collector.addError(new Throwable("first thing went wrong"));
            collector.addError(new Throwable("second thing went wrong"));
            collector.checkThat(getResult(), not(containsString("ERROR!")));
            // all lines will run, and then a combined failure logged at the end.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's in a different class and when I put `@Rule` in I am getting an error stating that `@Rule is disallowed for this location.`